# how to deal with case, when, and where in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one-to-many relation ship:

branches:

[image]

branch_working_hours:

[image]

What I am trying to achieve is to set a new column "intrvl" with correct open or close, consdering:

1. a branch can have 2 opening and closing hours a day (from1,to1 - from2,to2)
2. if current time is between (from1 and to1) or (from2 and to2) then open
3. if "to" is less than "from" (means branch opens after midnight), if current time greater than "from" then open
4. if "to" less than "from" and current time after midnight then check yesterday's "to", if greater than current time then open
5. Else close

```
select `branches`.*, 
    CASE
        WHEN 
            ((CURRENT_TIME() BETWEEN branch_working_hours.from1 AND branch_working_hours.to1 )
            OR (CURRENT_TIME() BETWEEN branch_working_hours.from2 AND branch_working_hours.to2) 
        
            OR branch_working_hours.is_24_hours_open= 1)
            AND EXISTS (
                SELECT * FROM branch_working_hours
                WHERE branch_working_hours.branch_id = branches.id AND branch_working_hours.day LIKE UCASE(DAYNAME(CURRENT_DATE()))
            )
        THEN 'OPEN'
        ELSE 
        CASE
            WHEN  
                ((branch_working_hours.to1 < branch_working_hours.from1 AND CURRENT_TIME() > branch_working_hours.from1)
                OR  (branch_working_hours.to2 < branch_working_hours.from2 AND CURRENT_TIME() > branch_working_hours.from2 ))
                AND EXISTS (
                    SELECT * FROM branch_working_hours
                    WHERE branch_working_hours.branch_id = branches.id AND branch_working_hours.day LIKE UCASE(DAYNAME(CURRENT_DATE()))
                  )
            THEN 'OPEN'
            ELSE 
                CASE
                    WHEN  
                        ((branch_working_hours.to1 < branch_working_hours.from1 AND CURRENT_TIME() BETWEEN '00:00:00' AND branch_working_hours.to1)
                        OR  (branch_working_hours.to2 < branch_working_hours.from2 AND CURRENT_TIME() BETWEEN '00:00:00' AND branch_working_hours.to2))
                        AND EXISTS (
                            SELECT * FROM branch_working_hours
                            WHERE branch_working_hours.branch_id = branches.id AND branch_working_hours.day LIKE UCASE(DAYNAME(SUBDATE(CURRENT_DATE(), 1)))
                        )
                    THEN 'OPEN'
                    ELSE 'CLOSED'
            end
        end
    end AS intrvl 
from `branches` 
inner join `branch_working_hours` on `branches`.`id` = `branch_working_hours`.`branch_id` 
group by `branches`.`id` 
having distance < ? 
order by `distance` asc
```

but this code most of the time returns wrong intrvl unless I add
where `branch_working_hours`.`day` LIKE UCASE(DAYNAME(CURRENT_DATE()))
but some times I need to check the yesterdays to get the current value

Comment: Don't nest `CASE` inside `ELSE` -- you can have multiple `WHEN` clauses in a single `CASE`, and they're tested in order.

Comment: `CASE WHEN` allows multiple WHEN parts, see [CASE WHEN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/case.html).  This should help to make your code more readable then the nested CASE WHEN you are currently using.  (Also data in text format, and not as image can help to reproduce your problem, which helps others (trying to ) help you)  This could also be done by adding a desired result with the give data.

Comment: Ok thank u didn't know that (about nested case). 
I tried to add it as a table but didn't figure it out so I posted them as images,
but even using one case I am still having the same output

Comment: Your data is all wrong. Every place is_24_hours_open = 1 then to1 should be 23:59:59 and not 11:59:59. ID2 how can something be open back in time? from2 23:34:33 is after to2 20:34:43?

Comment: I think you didn't read the code very well, because if is_24_hours_open is 1 then it will overrides the from and to (OR branch_working_hours.is_24_hours_open= 1))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution to it as follows:

```
CASE
    When    
        EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM branch_working_hours
        WHERE (branch_working_hours.branch_id = branches.id AND branch_working_hours.day LIKE UCASE(DAYNAME(CURRENT_DATE())))
        AND ((CURRENT_TIME() BETWEEN branch_working_hours.from1 AND branch_working_hours.to1 )
        OR (branch_working_hours.is_24_hours_open= 1)
        OR (CURRENT_TIME() BETWEEN branch_working_hours.from2 AND branch_working_hours.to2)
        OR (branch_working_hours.to1 < branch_working_hours.from1 AND CURRENT_TIME() > branch_working_hours.from1 )
        OR (branch_working_hours.to2 < branch_working_hours.from2 AND CURRENT_TIME() > branch_working_hours.from2))
) THEN 'OPEN'
    WHEN EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM branch_working_hours
        WHERE (branch_working_hours.branch_id = branches.id AND branch_working_hours.day LIKE UCASE(DAYNAME(SUBDATE(CURRENT_DATE(), 1))))
        AND (
            (branch_working_hours.to1 < branch_working_hours.from1 AND CURRENT_TIME() BETWEEN '00:00:00' AND branch_working_hours.to1)
            OR (branch_working_hours.to2 < branch_working_hours.from2 AND CURRENT_TIME() BETWEEN '00:00:00' AND branch_working_hours.to2)
        )
        ) THEN 'OPEN'

ELSE 'CLOSED'
end AS intrvl
```